# Как разместить изображение в верхнем левом углу контейнера с возможностью потом скрыть его?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlayout, qlabel, alignment

У меня есть контейнер `color_box`. Я бы хотел разместить в его левом верхнем углу небольшое изображение (примерно 30px*30px).

Мне нужно, чтобы картинка всегда оставалась в этом углу (в контейнере будут еще другие виджеты), т.е. не меняла свое положение при масштабировании окна.

Также мне очень важно знать, как скрыть это изображение. Пожалуйста, подскажите, как это сделать?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.resize(300, 400)

        self.box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)

        self.container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.container.setStyleSheet("background-color: yellow;")
        self.box.addWidget(self.container)
        self.color_box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.container)

        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button')
        btn.setStyleSheet("background-color: red;")
        self.color_box.addWidget(btn)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужна полоса, горизонтально группирующая виджеты:

```
# виджет-полоса
band = QWidget()

# Горизонталный лейаут
layout = QHBoxLayout()

# Метка для иконки
iconLabel = QLabel()
icon = QPixmap("пусть к картинке 30х30")
iconLabel.setPixmap(icon)

# Спейсер - служит для того, чтобы прижать виджеты к одной из сторон
# В нашем случае к левому краю
spacer = QSpacerItem(20, 20, QSizePolicy.Expanding) # расширяться горизонтально

# Добавляем необходимые виджеты
layout.addWidget(iconLabel)
...
# Спейсер должен идти последним
layout.addItem(spacer)

# устанавливаем лейаут в наш виджет
band.setLayout(layout)
```

Теперь необходимо поместить band в нужный контейнер, как я понимаю, в его верхнюю часть

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.resize(300, 400)
        
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('head3.png').scaled(30, 30))

        self.box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)

        self.container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.container.setStyleSheet("background-color: yellow;")
        self.box.addWidget(self.container)
        
        self.color_box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.container)

        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button')
        self.btn.setCheckable(True)
        self.btn.click()
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)
        self.btn.setStyleSheet("background-color: red;")
        
        self.color_box.addWidget(self.label, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignTop | QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.color_box.addWidget(self.btn, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom)
        
    def onClicked(self, state):
        if state:
            self.label.show()
        else:
            self.label.hide()        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

> Но можно ли поместить картинку так, чтобы картинка полностью прижалась к краям контейнера?
>
> А можно ли сделать так, чтобы к краям прижалось только изображение, а другие виджеты в контенере остались на своих местах?

---

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.resize(300, 400)
        
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('head3.png').scaled(30, 30))

        self.box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)

        self.container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.container.setStyleSheet("background-color: yellow;")
        self.box.addWidget(self.container)
        
        self.color_box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.container)
        self.color_box.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 20)                   # +++

        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button')
        self.btn.setFixedWidth(200)                                      # +++
        self.btn.setCheckable(True)
        self.btn.click()
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)
        self.btn.setStyleSheet("background-color: red;")
        
        self.color_box.addWidget(self.label, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignTop | QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.color_box.addWidget(self.btn, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom | QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter) # +++
        
    def onClicked(self, state):
        if state:
            self.label.show()
        else:
            self.label.hide()        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое. Но можно ли поместить картинку так, чтобы картинка полностью прижалась к краям контейнера?

Comment: @MAXIM045  да, можно. Добавьте `self.color_box.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)`

Comment: Еще раз спасибо:)

Comment: А можно ли сделать так, чтобы к краям прижалось только изображение, а другие виджеты в контенере остались на своих местах? Прошу прощения, что задаю так много вопросов

Comment: @MAXIM045 да, все можно. Много вопросов задавать не здорово, тем более в комментариях, которые обычно не читаются сообществом. Я не пробовал пример от Alexander Chernin, может быть в нем решены все вопросы, которые вы задаете ?

Comment: Там та же проблема - картинка не касается краев контейнера. Когда я задавал вопрос, имел ввиду то, что изображение полностью прижалось к краям. Почему-то тогда подумал, что такие детали можно не уточнять. Поэтому, я считал, что это все еще один вопрос

Comment: @MAXIM045 я добавил вариант решения. The End.